# Start menu cannot be changed and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer is missing

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

The Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer key is missing and my Start menu cannot be changed: there is no option to unpin tiles and I'm unable to drag anything. What was in that key? I saw a YouTube video in which there was one DWORD value and one string value, and I would create them manually, but I don't know what the full data was for the string value called StartLayoutFile.

Comment: I want to create that manually but I don't know what to put in data of value 'StartLayoutFile' . Can you pls tell me what I have to create?

Comment: In data there is something like: "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsof..." I don't know complete path.....I just want to know this complete path.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal for `Policies` subkeys to not exist if none of their corresponding Group Policy entries are configured. In fact, if you don't want any restrictions it's ideal for no policies to be in effect. Therefore, the absence of the key is not a problem and we don't need to create new entries there.

Your description of your Start menu problems matches the behavior of the *Prevent users from customizing their Start Screen* policy (unique ID `Microsoft.Policies.StartMenu:NoChangeStartMenu`). This is a user policy as opposed to a computer one, so its Registry entry will be somewhere under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` instead of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. Using the Element Inspector feature of my open-source application [Policy Plus](https://github.com/Fleex255/PolicyPlus), I determined that its Registry entry is named `NoChangeStartMenu` and located in this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

To lift the restrictions, delete that entry and logoff/logon. If it was actually set via Group Policy, you may need to unconfigure or disable the policy using the Local Group Policy Editor or Policy Plus.